# Access non-finalizable objects from finalizer

Tags: c#, finalizer

I want to access object without finalizer from finalizer of other instance.

I know that it is bad idea to access other finalizable object from finalizer because sequence of finalizer call is non-deterministic.

But what about accessing instances without finalizer from finalizer of other objects? I can not figure this out, the only found in the article http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29365 :

> This means that finalizers should never access other finalizable
> objects (objects without finalizers, however, are just fine)

Is any confirmation of this in MSDN?

Currently I want to acquire lock object with variable of type `object` but I want to be sure that it is OK and `object` instance is not freed from memory before accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently I want to acquire lock object with variable of type object

Accessing that object in your finalizer is fine, nothing happened to it.  Actually using it a *lock* statement, that's not so fine.  Blocking the finalizer thread tends to byte badly.  It has a time-out at program exit, it *must* complete and get everything finalized within two seconds.  You cannot afford a Monitor.TryEnter() to avoid tripping that timeout, that will be a bad resource leak.

And beware the code smell, you should not be releasing whatever native resource you wrote the finalizer for when other threads can still access it.  It is gospel that the finalizer can only run when *nobody* keeps a reference to the object anymore.  Which should also mean that there shouldn't be any point in locking anymore since no thread could have a reference anymore.  There is no need to protect shared state with a lock when nobody can read or write it.

Keep in mind that actually writing a finalizer tends to be almost always wrong, native resources should be finalized by their corresponding .NET wrapper class.  There are many, the low-level ones are the SafeHandle derived classes.

Comment: I use lock to set up flag and pulse it: lock (flagLock) {flag = true; Monitor.Pulse(flagLock); }. In fact I need to allocate and deallocate camera and this should be done in one thread - I want to encapsulate it and do in separate thread. In other thread flagLock is waiting while flag is set up to true to deallocate camera. I implemented IDisposable interface, but also want to provide fallback if camera is not disposed. And it is appeared that I don't know what is going on during finalization

Comment: Well, that doesn't sound good. That "other thread" is highly likely to not be running anymore by the time the finalizer runs, aborted by the CLR when it is busy unloading the AppDomain.  Nor would you use a lock to signal another thread, you use Set() on a wait handle.  It definitely does sound like you are abusing finalizers to have to do something they were not meant to do.  Specific advice is impossible without knowing how one "deallocates a camera".

Comment: This is what I have observed - other thread is aborted. It looks like I have two (bad) options for finalizer if Dispose was not called: 1. Solution described above - this does not work, as you described and I tried. 2. "Dispose camera" in finalizer thread - which is not good also... I don't know what is worse, as for now I am looking what I can do and looking for possible solutions. > "High odds that it just doesn't matter anyway since the process is exiting." - it looks true, but sometimes camera can not be initialized after rerun of app. Anyway, thanks for info - now it more clear for me

Comment: If something needs to be released for that camera firmware then it should be done inside the finalizer for a class that wraps the camera code.  Now you *know* that nobody is using the camera anymore and no locking or signaling is required.

Comment: The issue is that camera should be released in the same thread as initialized. And if it was initialized in UI thread (which is simplest way to initialize), it could not be released in the same thread as initialized (as required by API) if it is released in finalizer.

Comment: All the more reason to *not* use a finalizer.  High odds that it should be done at the end of Main().  You'll need help from the camera manufacturer to find out how to recover from an unexpected program abort.  That's always possible, a finalizer doesn't fix that either.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are not collected till the time they have a root. Assuming the `object` instance you are talking about is member of the object that is getting finalized, then that `object` has been alive all the time - because root is f-reachable queue.

However, I will strongly advise against any locking or blocking in finalizer. It could cause ugly deadlocks.